# Repeating truncate on an array item within element

Tags: javascript, polymer

```
        ready: function() {
    var len = 70;
    var p = this.$.tester;
    if (p) {
        var trunc = p.innerHTML;
        if (trunc.length > len) {

            trunc = trunc.substring(0, len);
            trunc = trunc.replace(/\w+$/, '');
            trunc += trunc.substring(0, len - 3) + '...';
            p.innerHTML = trunc;
        }
    } 

}
```

Trying to truncate text of a title to a max of 70 characters and replacing the last 3 with ellipsis.  I was only able to get it to apply to one application of the element when created however I wanted it to apply to all elements or templates created.  Is it possible for me to target an item within an array of a polymer tag?
Here is my attempt at it.  Sorry, still learning.  http://plnkr.co/edit/rHUrUEhpprTUEUJ7JrBh?p=preview

Comment: `array_map()` is possible what you are looking for

Comment: Tried using map however it cannot reference the array, cards.  Updated plnkr since I had the wrong one up.